# Cannot launch Vertex Hypertune Job (Google Cloud Platform)

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I am trying to use Vertex Hypertune from the google cloud console. I filled the forms to indicate my dataset, python package, compute resources, and so on.
Everything seems good up until the point where I submitted the job, I got an instant error (so probably it is not an issue from my code because there is no way it has even been run):

```
Unable to parse `training_pipeline.training_task_inputs` into hyperparameter tuning task `inputs` defined in the file gs://google-cloud-aiplatform/schema/trainingjob/definition/hyperparameter_tuning_task_1.0.0.yaml
```

I am really confused about why I get this error as I launched a training job without hyperparameter tuning with the same arguments and it worked just fine.

Any help would be truly appreciated

Note: I used a tabular dataset that comes from a BigQuery table (loaded with the dataset functionality). Default parameters were chosen for this dataset.
I picked the tensorflow 1.15 pre-built container and added my python code in an archive .tar.gz (generated with `python setup.py sdist`).
I configured only one hyperparameter (learning rate, double, between 0.001 and 0.1 to maximize 'accuracy', as declared in hypertune) and picked the lightest standard machine (n1-standard-4).

EDIT: Following the comment of @Jofre, it works now so it was probably originated by a temporary UI bug.

Comment: Could you provide more information about the configuration for the job you're trying to launch?

Comment: Google support here. There was a bug with the console UI that triggered the error, but the bug is fixed now. Can you try again? This will help in understanding if this was only related to that bug, or if there's something else going on. For future reference, if there is an actual reproducible bug with a GCP product, you can report it in Google's issue tracker: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Comment: @Jofre it works now, all good !

Comment: @Jofre Could you please look at this similar issue as well? It seems like a console UI error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73557938/vertex-ai-unknown-custom-training-job-error